# How to create your own fields and upload docs in Apache Solr?

Tags: java, xml, search, solr, lucene

I'm just playing around with Solr for the first time. Got it installed and running on Ubuntu Server, posted the sample xml docs that were inside the exampledocs directory and was able to search for keywords like "monitor", "apple" and "Dell" since these are in the example files.

Now I want to add my own docs with custom fields. This is what was there by default in scheme.xml:

```
 <fields>
   <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the 
       <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
       Norms are omitted for primitive (non-analyzed) types by default.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a
       given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be
       stored for best performance.
     termPositions: Store position information with the term vector.  
       This will increase storage costs.
     termOffsets: Store offset information with the term vector. This 
       will increase storage costs.
     default: a value that should be used if no value is specified
       when adding a document.
   -->

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="sku" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="alphaNameSort" type="alphaOnlySort" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="features" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="includes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />

   <field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />

   <!--
   The following store examples are used to demonstrate the various ways one might _CHOOSE_ to
    implement spatial.  It is highly unlikely that you would ever have ALL of these fields defined.
    -->
   <field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- Common metadata fields, named specifically to match up with
     SolrCell metadata when parsing rich documents such as Word, PDF.
     Some fields are multiValued only because Tika currently may return
     multiple values for them.
   -->
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- catchall text field that indexes tokens both normally and in reverse for efficient
        leading wildcard queries. -->
   <field name="text_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- non-tokenized version of manufacturer to make it easier to sort or group
        results by manufacturer.  copied from "manu" via copyField -->
   <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

   <field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- Uncommenting the following will create a "timestamp" field using
        a default value of "NOW" to indicate when each document was indexed.
     -->
   <!--
   <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
     -->

   <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
        will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
        RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
        a "*" only at the start or the end.
        EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
        Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
        both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.  -->
   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_pi"  type="pint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />

   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing 
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error. 
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want 
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default --> 
   <!--dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" /-->

 </fields>
```

and the default example files looked like:

```
<add><doc>
  <field name="id">3007WFP</field>
  <field name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</field>
  <field name="manu">Dell, Inc.</field>
  <field name="cat">electronics</field>
  <field name="cat">monitor</field>
  <field name="features">30" TFT active matrix LCD, 2560 x 1600, .25mm dot pitch, 700:1 contrast</field>
  <field name="includes">USB cable</field>
  <field name="weight">401.6</field>
  <field name="price">2199</field>
  <field name="popularity">6</field>
  <field name="inStock">true</field>
  <!-- Buffalo store -->
  <field name="store">43.17614,-90.57341</field>
</doc></add>
```

I replaced the fields in the schema.xml file with my own custom ones:

```
<fields>
  <field name="user_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="about" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="music" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="movies" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="occupation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
```

and tried to post this doc named mydoc.xml:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="user_id">foobar</field>
        <field name="about">I am a somebody</field>
        <field name="music">pop, rock</field>
        <field name="movies">titanic</field>
        <field name="occupation">web developer</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

when I tried to post using the same old command:

```
java -jar post.jar mydoc.xml
```

This is the error I received:

```
SimplePostTool: version 1.4
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file mydoc.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #400 ERROR: [doc=null] unknown field 'user_id'
```

I also noticed that if I restart the Solr service it fails to load Solr Admin, giving the message:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/admin/. Reason:

    Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml
```

followed by a bunch of other java type errors...

If I remove my own custom fields from schema.xml and restart Solr, it loads Solr Admin just fine.

So I'm at a loss here, how can I add my own custom fields and be able to post my docs to Solr?

Comment: You don't have a field named user_id in schema.xml.

Comment: @bmargulies yeah I do, look at the part where I posted what I replaced schema.xml's default fields with.

Comment: Not in your running instance, you didn't, or you wouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, I forgot to update this:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

to be:

```
<uniqueKey>user_id</uniqueKey>
```

at the bottom of schema.xml. Another issue was when I search using the `*:*` in Solr admin, everything was fine but when I searched via a string (keyword) it gave a `undefined field text` error. To fix that I had to add this as one of my fields:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```